# dictionary with nested list values to single list of values

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make single list of values in dictionary for each key. Bellow is problem. I am trying to parse list in Jinja and looks better to convert them into one before taking to template.

## Problem:

`{'EFTPOS': [[10.0, 5.0], 15.0], 'StoreDeposit': [[5.0, 6.0], 11.0]}`

## Result:

`{'EFTPOS': [10.0, 5.0, 15.0], 'StoreDeposit': [5.0, 6.0, 11.0]}`

Comment: you can use itertools chain to flatten the list.

Comment: in ```for-loop```, ```itertools.chain(value of dict)``` created another outer list, however, inside list didn't change

Comment: Yes, It won't work as it contains mix of floats and list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code snippet.I have defined a method to remove the nested list and convert it into a flat list.

```py
output = []
def rmNest(ls): 
    for i in ls: 
        if type(i) == list: 
            rmNest(i) 
        else: 
            output.append(i)
    return output


a_dict = {'EFTPOS': [[10.0, 5.0], 15.0], 'StoreDeposit': [[5.0, 6.0], 11.0]}

new_dict = {}

for i in a_dict:
    new_dict[i] = rmNest(a_dict[i])
    output = []
```